# excel 2010 Vba, looping through named ranges, Run-time error '1004':

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am assigning the same Macro to several OptionButtons.
I try to determine in which named Range the cklicked OButton is located.
So I get the Cell of the Button and loop through all named Ranges in my Worksheet to find Intersecting ones

My Code so far:

```
Sub OptionField()
Dim r As Range
Dim nm As Name
Set r = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell

For Each nm In ActiveSheet.Names
  If InRange(r, ActiveSheet.Range(nm)) = True Then           
  'Loop with ActiveSheet.Range(nm) seems to cause this issue
   Debug.Print nm.Name
  End If
Next nm
End Sub

Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
'returns True if Range1 is within Range2
 Dim InterSectRange As Range
 Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)
 InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
 Set InterSectRange = Nothing
 End Function
```

Within small variations in my Code I get two Error Messages which point me both to the same bug

Error message 1:
Application-defined or object-defined error

Error message 2:
Run-time error '1004':
 Method Range of object '_Global' failed

I did find the documentation on msdn, but I just fail to 'get it' or how to fix it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510/en-us

So i know VBA is hogging a reference and I need to release it, what irritates me is that the loop works fine for several iterations ( not just the first time) and then fails...

***Edit:*** it fails when a named Range refers to the same cells as a previous one does.
So that clears up the iteration thing

I tried to modify the loop to this, but it changes nothing with the referencing..

```
For Each nm In ActiveSheet.Names
Dim t As Range
Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(nm) 'it stops working here, when an ranges with same cells are called    
 If InRange(r, t) = True Then      
   Debug.Print nm.Name
  End If
Set t = Nothing
Next nm
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know if any of this will actually help, but here are some ideas to change it around and see if anything sticks: 1) Set `r` and `nm` to nothing at the end of the subroutine. 2) Dim a boolean and set the `InRange`call to that instead of using it directly in the `If` statement. 3) Dim another range object and assign that to `ActiveSheet.Range(nm)` as the first step in the loop (setting it back to nothing at the end). 4) Add `Debug.Print nm.RefersTo` before the `If` in the loop to make sure than `nm` refers to a valid range.

Comment: Does it always fail on the same button or at the same named range? (I.E., does the immediate window always show the same list of named ranges before it errors out?)

Comment: First, thanks for having a look at my problem. Sadly none of the change arounds of your first comment did do anything differently. 
But I now know that it stops after a named range that has a different name but refers to the same cells as another one does.

Comment: I do have a work-around now, but I don't like it as it only works because I know how the named ranges are structured in this specific case. Plus I proably will need a functioning loop through ranges again soon . So any suggestions on how to free up the reference to the same range is still tremendously helpful

Comment: By the by, I'm assuming all these ranges are scoped to just the active sheet, right? They're not on the Workbook scope?

Comment: yeah, all ranges are on the worksheet scope

Answer (score 0):

Does this improve the situation??

```
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
    'returns True if Range1 is within Range2
    Dim InterSectRange As Range

    InRange = False
    If Range1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Range1 is nothing"
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Range2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Range2 is nothing"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set InterSectRange = Intersect(Range1, Range2)
    InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
    Set InterSectRange = Nothing
 End Function
```

**EDIT#1**

Additionally, in the sub *OptionField()*, the named ranges are probably over-specified.  Change:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(nm)
```

to simply:

```
Range(nm)
```

**EDIT#2**

for example

```
Sub demo2()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    MsgBox r.Address
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.r.Address
End Sub
```

the first MsgBox works, but the second one fails...........this is because once **r** has been fully qualified, it does not need a worksheet to qualify it again.

Comment: sadly it doesn't, my ranges are valid references. The problem is caused by a double reference

Comment: You may be **over-specifying** the range...try *Range(nm)* in place of *ActiveSheet.Range(nm)*

Comment: nice thought, but not the solution. 
Can you generally over-specify stuff and what are usually the effects? 
Didn't encounter it so far and am honestly corious.

Comment: @SpaceFrog  See my **EDIT#2**